# TabHost: make all tabs unselected

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to unselect all the elements in the TabHost. I guess I can make a stub tab, which will have a width of 0dp. Is it a way to go ? How is it done -how do I apply style to one particular tab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the approach your going with Id suggest you create your own Tab View for the "fake tab".

Something like this

```
private class TabView extends FrameLayout  {
    public TabView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        View indicator = new View(c);
        //Might even wanna go for 0 here?
        LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(1, 1);
        indicator.setLayoutParams(params);

        addView(indicator);
    }
}
```

Then just add it to your TabHost in the following way :

```
    TabView fakeTab = new TabView(this, 0, "faketab");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("about").setIndicator(fakeTab);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

When you want to display all tabs as unselected you simple make the TabHost select your fake tab.

Comment: It's not enough clear to me. Could you elucidate with a more practical example ?

Comment: regarding your class constructor I had to write `TabView fakeTab = new TabView(_activity);_tabHost.addTab(_tabHost.newTabSpec("fake").setIndicator(fakeTab));` and it says: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content

Comment: Yeah, usually you put .setContent(Intent) after the .setIndicator() part. Maybe you have to provide content for the tab, you can put a Intent there but make sure nothing happens in the onTabChangedListener

Comment: okay, got it working but now this fake-tab shows me white space with width equal to other non-fake tabs. Is there any property that makes tabs stretch this way ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could try to change the layout params of the tab itself. Put this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, 0)); in the TabView.

Comment: Have you tried extending a different layout? Maybe LinearLayout behaves differently.

Comment: It's all the same - would you mind posting a working example ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627940/how-do-i-make-all-tabs-in-a-tabhost-unselected#comment15399342_11627940

Answer (score 2):

To make the tab stretch away:

```
fakeTab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```