# How do I make all tabs in a TabHost unselected

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to show tab content on occasion, otherwise the area must be filled with "non-tabhost" data.However, tabs should be visible and when user clicks any of those tabs "non-tabhost" must be hidden and appropriate tab content must become visible.

It's something connected to a fake tab creation ?

Give an example of creating TabHost with tabs unselected. 
Thanks.

Comment: So why use tabHost? use buttons instead

Comment: thats what I gonna do - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I usually do is, add an extra `Tab` and use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` to hide it. THis will just hide the tab button from the user, and the `Tab` will still be there, in the "background" and you can programmatically select it, by using `tabHost.setCurrentTab(0)`. I also usually keep this tab as the first one.

Comment: could you be more specific ? How do I get these tabs isntantiated ? How do I retrieve the tab that should be hidden ?

Comment: have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026653/how-to-hide-a-tab-in-android-tab-layout to see how you can hide a single tab. by selecting the hidden tab.. all the other tabs will remain unselected..

Comment: How to hide the dummy tab initially? I have tried using `android:visibility="gone"` for the tab in the layout file, but that didn't work. And there doesn't seem to be a `setVisiblity()` method for the tab when I obtain it using `TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);`

Answer (score 3):

1.copy the code where you want to tabs make unselected

```
 tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
```

2.Override on Tabselected Listener and paste the following code

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override`enter code here
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                 tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#EB1C23"));
                tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.BLACK, Color.RED);
              viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}


            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
               tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#EB1C23"));
                tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.BLACK, Color.RED);
              viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            }
        });
```